# Function call inside useEffect not firing in jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that, on button click sends the updated value to parent via `props.OnValChange`. This is implemented in the `useEffect` hook.
If I console log the useEffect I can see it being called. But in my test when I do `expect(prop.OnValChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` it says it was called 0 times.

Component:

```
const MyComp = ({OnValChange}) => {
    const [ val, setVal ] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("before");
        OnValChange(val);
        console.log("after");
    }, [val]);

    return (
        <button onClick={() => setVal(val + 1)}>Count</button>
    )
}
```

Test:

```
it("Sends val to parent when button is clicked", () => {
    const prop = {
        OnValChange: jest.fn();
    }

    const control = mount(<MyComp {...prop} />);

    expect(prop.OnValChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    control.find(button).simulate("click");
    expect(prop.OnValChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
})
```

Comment: this is a functional component, therefore there is no `this`. Your `props` object is just the first parameter to the `MyComp` function (which you'd have to name).

Comment: @Derek You're right, just a minor typing error. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useEffect` will always be called once when the component is initially mounted, and will be called a second time when you trigger a button click, so the correct test should be like this

[image: Edit determined-heyrovsky-22zpv]

```js
it("Sends val to parent when button is clicked", () => {
    const prop = {
        OnValChange: jest.fn();
    }

    const control = mount(<MyComp {...prop} />);

    expect(prop.OnValChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    control.find(button).simulate("click");
    expect(prop.OnValChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
})
```

---

If you are always 0 times, I suspect that it is a problem with the version of `enzyme-adapter-react-16`. When I switch the version to `1.13.0`, there will be the same problem as you, you can try `enzyme -adapter-react-16` updated to the latest version.

Comment: I have logic in my code that restrict useEffect to run on the initial mount so `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);` is correct. This doesn't answer my question though. Once the click fires, I still get `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` as 0.

Comment: I modified the example in CodeSandbox to limit the initial run. After clicking, get the value of `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` 1. You can click on CodeSandbox again.

Are you sure that your `enzyme-adapter-react-16` version is the latest `1.14.0`?

Or you can create an example of CodeSandbox, can I help you debug it?

Comment: I updated enzyme-adapter-react-16 to 1.14.0 and the problem still persists. I'll have a look at your codesandbox example. Thanks.

Comment: I just updated enzyme -adapter-react-16 and the types for it again and now it magically works! Thanks!